# Sum values to show in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my admin panel i have a view of orders of day, individually is ok, but i want to count and sum the values (count number of orders) and (sum value from orders).

**$pedido->valor_pedido (is the individual price from order)**

My code is like this.

```
if(count($pedidos) > 0){ foreach($pedidos as $pedido){ $totalHoje += $valorCompra; ?>
<tr onclick="window.location='<?=base_url();?>index.php/adm/pedidos/alterar/<?=$pedido->id;?>'" style="cursor:pointer" target='_blank'>

    <td width="50">
        <?=$pedido->id;?>
    </td>
    <td class="pedidonome">
        <?=strtolower($pedido->nome ? $pedido->nome : $pedido->razao_social);?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo getPagamento($pedido->pagamento);?>
    </td>
    <td>R$
        <?=$pedido->frete;?>
    </td>
    <td>R$
        <?=$pedido->valor_pedido;?>
    </td>
    <td><span class="<?=$pedido->situacao;?>"><?=$pedido->situacao;?></span></td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you the right way you need to get a sum of orders, that's how you can do this:

```
    <?php if(count($pedidos) > 0): ?>
                <?php $sum = 0.00; ?>
                <?php foreach($pedidos as $pedido): ?>
                    <tr onclick="window.location='<?=base_url();?>index.php/adm/pedidos/alterar/<?=$pedido->id;?>'" style="cursor:pointer" target='_blank'>
                        <?php $sum += $pedido->valor_pedido; ?>
                        <td width="50">
                            <?=$pedido->id;?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="pedidonome">
                            <?=strtolower($pedido->nome ? $pedido->nome : $pedido->razao_social);?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo getPagamento($pedido->pagamento);?>
                        </td>
                        <td>R$
                            <?=$pedido->frete;?>
                        </td>
                        <td>R$
                            <?=$pedido->valor_pedido;?>
                        </td>
                        <td><span class="<?=$pedido->situacao;?>"><?=$pedido->situacao;?></span></td>

                    </tr>
                   ...................
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?= 'Total: ' . $sum ?>
   <?php endif; ?> //end if statement
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pwd","db name);

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"select count(1) FROM tablename");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  $total = $row[0];
  echo "Total rows: " . $total;
?>
```